# SPF / DKIM / DMARC with AWS SES dns setup

Tags: dns, amazon-ses, spf, dkim, dmarc

I've been trying to figure out how to set up DNS for the domain that we use to distribute emails via AWS SES API.

Taking domain like `example.com` I have verified DKIM by using 3 generated CNAME records.
I then enabled `MAIL FROM Doman`, where I was only able to generate subdomain `mail.example.com` with the following records:

```
MX
name: mail
value: 10 feedback-smtp.eu-west-2.amazonses.com.
```

```
TXT
name: mail
value: "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"
```

I also have a `TXT` record for `DMARK` as:

```
name: _dmark
value: "v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; fo=1; pct=25; rua=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com ruf=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com"
```

For sender email address I use `mail@example.com` which uses all the same verification.

My DMARC policy specifies relaxed alignment for DKIM as the From header uses email address with plain domain `mail@example.com` while MAIL FROM subdomain `mail.example.com`

All emails at the moment bounce back and I'm not entirely sure why.
Also - when previewing the bounced message - From shows as `From: MAILER-DAEMON@eu-west-2.amazonses.com` rather than verified sub-domain `mail.example.com` - not entirely sure how long does it take for changes to take effect, but everything has been verified a couple of hours ago and it's still failing.

I have the sending email `mail@example.com` set up with Gsuite - so it also has a set of standard Gmail MX records.

**Question**

Should I instead remove the SPF TXT record for `mail.example.com` and instead create one which will include subdomain as well as `amazonses.com`?:

```
TXT
name: 
value: "v=spf1 include:mail.example.com include:amazonses.com ~all"
```

Anything else that could be done to make it all work?
I learn as I go with it so perhaps I miss something obvious, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: SPF checks done on mailfrom and after configuring custom mail from, the txt record for mail.example.com should be present and should include amazonses.com, seems like you're doing all auth correct, there isn't any importance of including mail.example.com in txt record , do you record bounce email to see what is it about ? bounce may be because SES IP is blacklisted somewhere,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will address your specific problem, however the SPF record may be better as:

```
TXT
name: 
value: "v=spf1 a include:amazonses.com ~all"
```

Your first version doesn't include "a" which would pick up "example.com" form the A record.

The second example will cause circular reference warnings.

Given you changed the mail from domain your SPF will need to include "example.com"

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively old question but I'm still answering it because it has many views and it is related to a common mistake in setting up SPF and DMARC records for SES.

When you want to setup SPF and DMARC records in DNS for any mail server, including AWS SES, you have to select your sending (FROM) domain clearly and use the same domain name in all configurations. For example, if you want to send emails from the root domain of `example.com`, you need to use `example.com` in both your SPF record and your DMARC record (as well as your DKIM records if you decide to set that up too).

In this question, you are mixing a subdomain of `mail.example.com` (not the root domain) in some records while it seems you intend to setup SPF and DMARC for the root domain of `example.com`.

You need to pay attention that every subdomain will be treated completely differently when it comes to email protocols, including SPF and DMARC.

This mistake is very common because often when you are asked to setup SPF and DMARC for a mail server, you might not actually have admin access to the correct DNS and mail server yet, especially for the root domain. So, when you go into the AWS SES dashboard, you might think that you need to create a new subdomain to be able to create the necessary records for your DNS.

The solution here is to first ask for admin access to the correct DNS and email service for the root domain (or subdomain) that you want to setup SPF and DMARC (and DKIM) records for and then, start making the configuration changes required and only using the domain name that you want to use in your sending (FROM) address.

To answer the specific question asked:

No, you don't need to add `include:mail.example.com` in your SPF record if you want to send emails from `example.com` domain. In this case, you need to find out which email service is being used for sending emails from your root domain and then, include IP address or the provided `include:` statement from that email service into your SPF record.